# Polar coordinates to rectangular

Tags: polar-coordinates

I was asked to convert $r=\frac4{\cos \theta -4 \sin \theta}$ to rectangular coordinates.

So far, I know that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$.

I multiplied both sides by $r$ to get $r^2 = \frac4{r\cos \theta -4 r\sin \theta}$

I want to assume that because of what I know, that $r^2 = \frac4{x-4y}$.

Maybe I can square root both sides to get the final answer - or did I make a mistake?

Comment: The cos$thetha$-4sin$theta$ is in the denominator. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: At least use some parentheses...

Comment: Second time lucky ? 
\begin{eqnarray*}
r= \frac{4}{\cos \theta -4 \sin \theta}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Shall I edit for you ?

Comment: Multiplyng by $r$ we obtain $r^2=\frac{4r}{\cos \theta -4 \sin \theta}$ but it is inconclusive (that was my interpretation in editing, please correct if I'm wrong).

Comment: Shouldn't you **divide** both sides by $r$ to get $$\frac4{r\cos\theta-4r\sin\theta}=\frac4{x-4y}$$ on the right hand side?

Comment: @NeilH Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

$$r=\frac4{\cos \theta -4 \sin \theta}\implies r\cos \theta-4r \sin \theta=4$$